# How many ways to place $3$ points in a grid?

Tags: combinatorics

This question follows on from this one:

> [Does it exist a way how to find the ways to get from one point to another when certain points must be avoided in a grid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588703/does-it-exist-a-way-how-to-find-the-ways-to-get-from-one-point-to-another-when-c)

The accepted answer gives the result in this case, I am wondering how many ways there are to place $3$ (or more) dots on a grid such that each dot is non-left and non-down and non-same of the previous point?

For example:

```
..Z.
..Y.
.X..
```

In an $m\times m$ grid the first dot can go in:

$$\large\sum_{1\le i_0\le m\\1\le j_0\le n\\2\le i_0+j_0\le n+m-2} 1$$

places, which allows for the other two dots to be placed. This evaluates to $nm-3$.

For the second dot, given that the first is at $(x,y)$, we have:

$$\large\sum_{x\le i_1\le m\\y\le j_1\le n\\x+y+1\le i_1+j_1\le n+m-x-y-1} 1$$

which avoids the first dot, and leaves space for the last dot, which is given by (for a different $(x,y)$):

$$\large\sum_{x\le i_2\le m\\y\le j_2\le n\\x+y+1\le i_2+j_2\le n+m-x-y} 1$$

All together:

$$\large\sum_{1\le i_0\le m\\1\le j_0\le n\\2\le i_0+j_0\le n+m-2} \large\sum_{i_0\le i_1\le m\\j_0\le j_1\le n\\i_0+j_0+1\le i_1+j_1\le n+m-i_0-j_0-1} \large\sum_{i_1\le i_2\le m\\j_1\le j_2\le n\\i_1+j_1+1\le i_2+j_2\le n+m-i_1-j_1} 1$$

What is the closed form for this?

For a check, $m=n=3$ should give $37$.

```
ZZZ  YZZ  -ZZ  --Z  -ZZ  -YZ  --Z
YZZ  ---  -ZZ  --Z  -YZ  ---  --Y
X--  X--  XYZ  X-Y  X--  X--  X--
```

```
YZZ  -YZ  -ZZ  --Z
X--  X--  XYZ  X-Y
---  ---  ---  ---
```

```
-ZZ  -YZ  --Z  --Z 
-YZ  ---  --Z  --Y
-X-  -X-  -XY  -X-
```

```
XYZ  --Z
---  --Y 
---  --X
```

```
-YZ  --Z
-X-  -XY 
---  ---
```

Comment: I think in your $3\times 3$ your second and third sets  may each be missing an example e.g. where the top row would look like `- - Z` and the middle row like `X - Y`.  So $37$ possibilities

Comment: @Henry; thanks, fixed.

Comment: The $m=n$ case may be the numbers tabulated at http://oeis.org/A050351

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think not: for example with $m=n=2$ I get $2$ (the bottom row of the $3 \times 3$ example) rather than $5$.  For $m=n$, I get $0,2,37,216,800,2290,5537,11872$

Comment: I think for given $m$ you get a cubic in $n$.  For example with $m=4$ I think it may be $\frac13(10n^3+2n)$

Comment: @Henry, I get five. $$\matrix{y&y\cr x&y\cr},\qquad\matrix{x&y\cr\cdot&\cdot\cr},\qquad\matrix{\cdot&y\cr\cdot&x\cr}$$

Comment: Oh, wait, that would be a different question. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

As an empirical result, I found these numbers for an $m \times n$ rectangle

```
m \ n        1    2   3    4       5       6       7        8

1            0    0   1    4      10      20      35       56
2            0    2  10   28      60     110     182      280
3            1   10  37   92     185     326     525      792
4            4   28  92  216     420     724    1148     1712
5           10   60 185  420     800    1360    2135     3160
6           20  110 326  724    1360    2290    3570     5256
7           35  182 525 1148    2135    3570    5537     8120
8           56  280 792 1712    3160    5256    8120    11872
```

and these seem to have the closed expression

$$\frac{mn}{36}(m^2n^2+3m^2n+3mn^2+2m^2-9mn+2n^2-12m-12n+22)$$

For $m=n$, i.e. an $n\times n$ square, these values are $0,2,37,216,800,2290,5537,11872, \ldots$ which can be expressed by $$\frac{n^2}{36}(n^4+6n^3-5n^2-24n+22)$$

Comment: The numbers for $m=2$ appear to be http://oeis.org/A006331 and as they're all even we can divide by two to get http://oeis.org/A000330

Comment: @GerryMyerson And for $m=3$ they are [A096000](https://oeis.org/A096000) offset, but that may just be that for any fixed $m$ the result is a cubic in $n$, and OEIS has many of those