# Number of possible paths on a 6x6 grid, with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider a 6x6 grid, with point A ($0,0$) being the bottom left, and point B $(6,6)$ being the top right vertex. We need to find the total possible paths from $A$ to $B$ , of length $12$ units, such that we dont pass through a $2\times2$ grid containing:$(3,3),(3,4),(4,3),(4,4)$.

**Approach**: Suppose there wasn't any restriction , and we simply had to count the number of paths from $A$ to $B$. Then, let $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ be the number of right, left,up and down moves respectively. We then have a system of equations:

- $a+b+c+d=12$
- Horizontal distance= $a-b=6$
- Vertical distance=$c-d=6$

Which leads to the solution $a=c=6$ and $b=d=0$. So we basically have to find total arrangements of $6$ "right moves" and $6$ "up moves" , which are obviously going to be $\dfrac{12!}{6!6!}$.

This seems to be a reasonable approach, but I am having a hard time trying to adjust this to account for the restriction(s)...

The gist of what I am trying to figure out seems to be: **How to mathematically express the statement "doesn't pass through $(p,q)$"?**

A small insight that might help with the computations, is that any path containing $(4,4)$ must also contain either $(4,3)$ or $(3,4)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it exist a way how to find the ways to get from one point to another when certain points must be avoided in a grid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588703/does-it-exist-a-way-how-to-find-the-ways-to-get-from-one-point-to-another-when-c)

Answer (score 2):

For this, since it is such a small example, it is going to be easiest to just draw a $6\times 6$ square (*or a $7\times 7$ array*) and mark the vertices with the number of different paths to get to that point from the start, filling out the numbers close to start first and finding the values further away by adding the values in the spaces who lead to it... having crossed out the illegal positions ahead of time.

$$\begin{bmatrix}~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\1&~&~&~&~&~&~\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\1&~&~&~&~&~&~\\1&1&~&~&~&~&~\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\1&~&~&~&~&~&~\\1&2&~&~&~&~&~\\1&1&1&~&~&~&~\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&X&X&~&~\\1&~&~&X&X&~&~\\1&3&~&~&~&~&~\\1&2&3&~&~&~&~\\1&1&1&1&~&~&~\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\~&~&~&~&~&~&~\\1&~&~&X&X&~&~\\\color{blue}{1}&\color{red}{4}&~&X&X&~&~\\1&\color{blue}{3}&6&~&~&~&~\\1&2&3&4&~&~&~\\1&1&1&1&1&~&~\end{bmatrix}$$

Here are the first few lines filled out.  Colored in red, the $4$ here for instance was calculated by adding the blue $3$ and blue $1$.

If we were to continue in this fashion, each number in the grid corresponds to the number of paths possible from the starting vertex to that position in the grid, and in particular the number in the top right corner will be the one you are interested in.

The final array will look like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&7&28&49&70&112&224\\1&6&21&21&21&42&112\\1&5&15&X&X&21&70\\1&4&10&X&X&21&49\\1&3&6&10&15&21&28\\1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$